# What does "-install" do in the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

At my job, the procedure to transform a .bat file into a windows service is described as:

```
-Start the command prompt as an Administrator

-Type the following command ActiveTask.bat -install
```

I have never seen that way of making a .bat as a windows service and when I look online : http://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/command_line_options/#-install-options I can't find "-install" with no parameters. Note that I can't test it myself because I don't have admin rights on my computer. My question is : Should I change the procedure to executing a .bat file that creates a scheduled task at startup or keep this one? Any other alternative? I need a user to install a program on his computer that starts without the need of logging in and with the simplest steps as possible.

Comment: What happens when you type `where ActiveTask.bat` at a commandline?

Comment: I don't have the file, that's just the procedure. I need to recreate the file so that the procedure works, or change the procedure but keep the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveTask.bat is a script that will look for the -install parameter to be set. If this is the case, it will install itself as service.

How it does that is very specific to this script, and its not a windows feature. In order to find out how, edit the ActiveTask.bat file with a texteditor.

Comment: I don't have any files, only the procedure and I have to re-create the .bat with only that procedure as hint. So I should look into making a windows service via batch script right?

Comment: @loli [How to install a windows service from command line specifying name and description?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18508628)